# Calculation of inherit value for font-size

Tags: css

I am reading [CSS Spec 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html) and got this question.

Regarding inheritance, it says:

> When inheritance occurs, elements inherit **computed values**. The
>   computed value from the parent element becomes both the specified
>   value and the computed value on the child.

But for the `inherit` value of a property, it says:

> Each property may also have a cascaded value of 'inherit', which means
>   that, for a given element, the property takes the same **specified value**
>   as the property for the element's parent.

Does it mean that: if I specify `font-size: 2em` to parent and `font-size: inherit` to child, the result is the same as specifying `font-size: 2em` to child (because `2em` is its parent's **specified value**)?

From my sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/189tda5g/), it is not the case:

```css
#parent {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#child-0 {
  font-size: inherit;
}
#child-1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">I am parent.
  <div id="child-0">I am child 0.</div>
  <div id="child-1">I am child 1.</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at [the `inherit` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit):

> Each property may also have a cascaded value of 'inherit', which means
>   that, for a given element, the property takes the same *specified value*
>   as the property for the element's parent.

So the question now is, *how are specified values handled*?

The answer is under [Computed Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#computed-value):

> 6.1.2 Computed values
>
> *Specified values* are **resolved to computed values** during the cascade [...]

and how are computed values handled?

> [...] 'em' and 'ex' units are
>   computed to pixel or absolute lengths.

(Emphasis added)

This means that when the child inherits the parents font size it will inherit its parents computed value in pixels (`px`), by default `2em` is 32px.

When the child is given its own `em` value, it will compute its value in px based on the computed value of its parent font size. `2em` will double the childs font-size.

In your example:

- 2em on the parent = 32px
- inherit on the child = 32px (the computed value of the parent)
- 2em on the child = 64px (the computed value of the child which is double the value of the parent)

This is reflected in your example:

```css
#parent {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#child-0 {
  font-size: inherit;
}
#child-1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">I am parent.
  <div id="child-0">I am child 0 and I inherit my parents computed font-size of 32px</div>
  <div id="child-1">I am child 1 and I double my font-size with 2em. This means that I have a font-size of 64px</div>
</div>
```